# PayPal internal server error while payment in Android app

Tags: android, paypal

I am developing Android app in which i have implemented `PayPal sdk` for payments. Their is wired thing happened to me when i was testing `PayPal` over production environment. This happen only once.

While i was testing i click on checkout button which redirects me to the `PayPal sdk` and i logged in with production username and password. When i click on pay button(`Paypal sdk`). i got server error with popup message that saying internal server error either "**Try Again**" or "**Cancel**". I clicked try again nothing happened dialog disappear.

When i click pay again this time result is ok and i was redirected to my app. But the problem is that Amount charged double to me. How can this happen. But i was redirected once in my app from `Paypal sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

I could be that around the time you were testing, the were some network problem which why the error message appeared and it was bale to run again afterward, are you still getting the same?